# C malloc() throws error on linux, not on mac

Tags: c, linux, macos, malloc

I have a function that parses a file and counts some stuff. The function is as follows:

```
int meta_counter(FILE *meta_file){
    int counter = 0;
    char *c;
    char line[1024];
    while ((c = fgets(line, sizeof(line), meta_file)) != NULL)
    {
        char *first = malloc(sizeof(c));
        strcpy(first,c);
        char *rest = strchr(first, ' ');
        *rest = 0;
        if (strcmp(first,"Start") != 0 && strcmp(first,"End") != 0) {
            //handle typos
            char *d = remove_white_spaces(c);
            replace_string(d,';',':');
            replace_string(d,'.',':');
            char *e = (char*)malloc(sizeof(d) + 1);
            remove_string(e, d, ' ');
            // put a ':' at the end of the line
            if (e[strlen(e)-1] != ':') e[strlen(e)] = ':';
            //count operators in line 'e'
            char *key = ":";
            char *ptr = e;
            while((ptr = strchr(ptr, ':')) != NULL) {
                counter++;
                ptr++;
            }
        }
    }
    rewind(meta_file);
    return counter;
}
```

When I compile and run the program on Mac OSX, everything goes great. But when I compile (compiles with no problem), and run on Linux, it gives me this kind of error:

```
*** Error in `./sim01': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000001bc7170 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x77725)[0x7f4cf974a725]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x819be)[0x7f4cf97549be]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_malloc+0x54)[0x7f4cf97565a4]
./sim01[0x4013d7]
./sim01[0x401f8b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f4cf96f3830]
./sim01[0x400a99]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00403000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 3145767                            /home/pregis/workspace/cpp-mars/Sim01/sim01
00602000-00603000 r--p 00002000 08:05 3145767                            /home/pregis/workspace/cpp-mars/Sim01/sim01
00603000-00604000 rw-p 00003000 08:05 3145767                            /home/pregis/workspace/cpp-mars/Sim01/sim01
01bc6000-01be7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f4cf4000000-7f4cf4021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f4cf4021000-7f4cf8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f4cf94bd000-7f4cf94d3000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 25559117                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f4cf94d3000-7f4cf96d2000 ---p 00016000 08:05 25559117                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f4cf96d2000-7f4cf96d3000 rw-p 00015000 08:05 25559117                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f4cf96d3000-7f4cf9893000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 25559903                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f4cf9893000-7f4cf9a92000 ---p 001c0000 08:05 25559903                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f4cf9a92000-7f4cf9a96000 r--p 001bf000 08:05 25559903                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f4cf9a96000-7f4cf9a98000 rw-p 001c3000 08:05 25559903                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f4cf9a98000-7f4cf9a9c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f4cf9a9c000-7f4cf9ac2000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 25559843                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f4cf9c91000-7f4cf9c94000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f4cf9cbe000-7f4cf9cc1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f4cf9cc1000-7f4cf9cc2000 r--p 00025000 08:05 25559843                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f4cf9cc2000-7f4cf9cc3000 rw-p 00026000 08:05 25559843                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f4cf9cc3000-7f4cf9cc4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffcdc988000-7ffcdc9a9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffcdc9c6000-7ffcdc9c8000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffcdc9c8000-7ffcdc9ca000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I found out that the error is in this line: `char *first = malloc(sizeof(c));`. I tried to increase the number inside of the malloc function (like times 1000, to make sure it could handle it), to see if the while loop runs more than once (it crashes on the second run), but it only ran for another (crashes on 3 now) iteration (should run several).

I imagine there must be something different going on on both compilers, so here are my gcc versions:

Mac OSX:

```
$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Linux (Ubuntu):

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sizeof c is the sizeof pointer.

Comment: Ther problem is here: `sizeof(c)`.

Comment: There are other problems, What happens if your line contains a `' '`  ? There are no calls to `free`. `sizeof(d)` is wrong too.

Comment: `if (e[strlen(e)-1] != ':') e[strlen(e)] = ':';` seems to overwrite the null terminator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say `sizeof(c)` I'm sure you're expecting it to return the size of the string. What it actually does is `sizeof(char*)` which usually is 8 bytes on a 64bit platform. Then you copy the whole line into that, which causes undefined behaviour.

Next you do the same with `sizeof(d)` which again is only 8 bytes.

This is very different for `sizeof(line)` since `line` is `char[1024]` and its size is known.

You might simplify the whole code by using `strdup()` which will do both the allocation and the copying in one go.

I can't see any `free()` calls there, which causes a memory leak. Especially bad in a loop.

Please learn how to use a debugger, it would show you immediately that you're allocating insufficient amount of memory. And learn how to release allocated memory.

Comment: Thanks! This was my first ever assignment in C, so I'm really inexperienced. Your suggestions worked, that's why it's the best answer. But there's still one question unanswered, why would that piece of code work on a mac osx and not on a linux machine?

Comment: @user2962392 Because the behaviour is undefined it may look like it's working, but anything can happen.

Answer (score 0):

In line         `char *first = malloc(sizeof(c));`, `sizeof(c)` does not return the size of the string, but the size of the `c` pointer: 8 as you are on a 64 bits machine.

You should try with: `char *first = malloc(sizeof(strlen(c) + 1));` to allocate the righte size.

One other solution, is to use `strdup` function:

```
/* alloctate memory to store string and copy the data*/
char *first = strdup(c);
```

**Warning:** Their is no trace of `free()` is your code...

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(c)` is the size of pointer to a char.

You may use `sizeof(line)` instead. 
Line is an array, sizeof works differently with arrays, It gives the total size of all the elements in the array.

One other alternative is to use `malloc(strlen(c)+1)`.